# Не работает action в form Html, что делать?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Мне нужно по нажатию на кнопку обратиться к серверу по определенному пути, нужно именно через Action, но он почему-то не работает, запросы не уходят

```
  <form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Фото товара</label>
        <input class="form-control adminInputPhoto" type="file" id="formFile" name="img">
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3 adminButton">Отправить</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Скрипт сервера

```
router.post('/profile', (req, res) => {
    res.json({mee: 'gsgsg'})
    console.log("gsg")
})
```

Comment: Возможно стоит указать в action путь `action="http://localhost:3000/profile"`, смотря на каком порту запущен сервер

Comment: Попробуйте убрать слеш: action="profile"

Comment: /action отправляет запрос на тот же порт, где запущен фронт.
Что бы отправить на сервер нужно воспользоваться советом @Senbonzakuraa, тогда запрос улетит на сервер